# How to use NIST SP 800-22 to check randomness of 128 bits output in AES?

Tags: aes, nist, statistical-test

I am trying NIST SP 800-22 to test the randomness of 128 bit output in AES, but i always get ***igamc: UNDERFLOW*** or ***Segmentation fault (core dumped)*** error.

My data file has 128 bit output format, for example as follows:

```
01101100010001011111011101010011011000000101111001111100010010111011111001010011101101000000111011011100011011101101100011011001
00000000101100000010110001100100101101000010010010110101100111110011011110010000100010001111011110101001100011100000100111000001
```

Here i have all 100.000 lines with capacity 12.899.967 bytes. I used the tool with the following operations:

```
 ./assess 128
           G E N E R A T O R    S E L E C T I O N
           ______________________________________

    [0] Input File                 [1] Linear Congruential
    [2] Quadratic Congruential I   [3] Quadratic Congruential II
    [4] Cubic Congruential         [5] XOR
    [6] Modular Exponentiation     [7] Blum-Blum-Shub
    [8] Micali-Schnorr             [9] G Using SHA-1

   Enter Choice: 0


                User Prescribed Input File: data/binaryformat2.txt

                S T A T I S T I C A L   T E S T S
                _________________________________

    [01] Frequency                       [02] Block Frequency
    [03] Cumulative Sums                 [04] Runs
    [05] Longest Run of Ones             [06] Rank
    [07] Discrete Fourier Transform      [08] Nonperiodic Template Matchings
    [09] Overlapping Template Matchings  [10] Universal Statistical
    [11] Approximate Entropy             [12] Random Excursions
    [13] Random Excursions Variant       [14] Serial
    [15] Linear Complexity

         INSTRUCTIONS
            Enter 0 if you DO NOT want to apply all of the
            statistical tests to each sequence and 1 if you DO.

   Enter Choice: 1

        P a r a m e t e r   A d j u s t m e n t s
        -----------------------------------------
    [1] Block Frequency Test - block length(M):         128
    [2] NonOverlapping Template Test - block length(m): 9
    [3] Overlapping Template Test - block length(m):    9
    [4] Approximate Entropy Test - block length(m):     10
    [5] Serial Test - block length(m):                  16
    [6] Linear Complexity Test - block length(M):       500

   Select Test (0 to continue): 0

   How many bitstreams? 99999

   Input File Format:
    [0] ASCII - A sequence of ASCII 0's and 1's
    [1] Binary - Each byte in data file contains 8 bits of data

   Select input mode:  0

     Statistical Testing In Progress.........

     Statistical Testing Complete!!!!!!!!!!!!

igamc: UNDERFLOW
igamc: UNDERFLOW
igamc: UNDERFLOW
igamc: UNDERFLOW
................
igamc: UNDERFLOW
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Even i tried adjusting the parameters back to 128 but still not working

```
        P a r a m e t e r   A d j u s t m e n t s
        -----------------------------------------
    [1] Block Frequency Test - block length(M):         128
    [2] NonOverlapping Template Test - block length(m): 128
    [3] Overlapping Template Test - block length(m):    128
    [4] Approximate Entropy Test - block length(m):     128
    [5] Serial Test - block length(m):                  128
    [6] Linear Complexity Test - block length(M):       128

   Select Test (0 to continue): 0
```

Can someone give me advice or hints to check the randomness of 128 bit output ?

Comment: Hiya Cat.  I don't   have a keyboard so can't  answer properly.  But, use 10 bits treats and just one single  long line of digits. Also accept  that NIST is poor at coding.

Comment: P.S. Don't  adjust  nothin'.

Comment: I am still interested in the problem. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Inverse Gamma functions are a bitch to compute.  I suggest that you try the suite with 8 bit/byte binary data.  Reformat. Once you've create the binary sample file, run `ent` or `ent3000` over it to see if you have sane samples.

Comment: @PaulUszak So how should `./assess` and `How many bitstreams?` be entered?